# WPF Expander Headers are not being populated when using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have implemented an Expander using a ListView, but the Header Text is not populating when attempting to bind to a property on the ViewModel. ReportCategoryTypeName is what I am attempting to bind to for the Expander header, but all the headers are blank.

If I hard code a text value everything works fine.

My code is based on: https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/ which I know is using code behind all the way.

This is the code behind:  ucAppReports.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace App.Pages
{
    public partial class ucAppReports : UserControl
    {
        public ucAppReports()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            CollectionView cv = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvReports.ItemsSource);
            PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("ReportCategoryTypeName");
            cv.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);

        }

    }
}
```

This is the ListView from ucAppReports.xaml

```
<ListView x:Name="lvReports"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Reports}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedReport}" Grid.Row="1" 
    Grid.Column="0" Background="Green" BorderBrush="Purple" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected"  Value="true" >
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Expander IsExpanded="False">
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ReportCategoryTypeName}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                            <!--<TextBlock Text="Hello" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />-->
                                            <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                            <TextBlock Text=" item(s)" FontSize="22" Foreground="Silver" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />-->
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>

    </ListView.GroupStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                        <!--<RowDefinition Height="22"></RowDefinition>-->
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Content="{Binding ReportName}" FontSize="14" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" ></Label>
                    <!--<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="Modififed Date:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="10" Width="79"></Label>
                        <Label Content="{Binding ModifiedDate}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  FontSize="10" Width="auto" Height="22"></Label>
                    </StackPanel>-->
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The ListView Items Source is Reports, and it is being correctly populated on the AppReportsViewModel.

If you uncomment this line then all the reports are grouped together properly. The only problem is that all the headers are Hello.

```
<!--<TextBlock Text="Hello" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />-->
```

Here is what the result looks like: The number of groups is correct, but the ReportCategoryTypeNames are not appearing.
[image]

Comment: Add your viewmodels and other logic that you have.

Comment: Check the output window during debugging, you can notice the binding error if there is any.

Comment: In your GroupItem ControlTemplate, the DataContext is an object of type MS.Internal.Data.CollectionViewGroupInternal. You can determine that by changing the binding on your textblock: `Text="{Binding}"`. Does that class have a property named `ReportCategoryTypeName`? I doubt very much that it does. But it probably has something that'll give you the group key value.

Comment: It's [a `CollectionViewGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup?view=netframework-4.8), and its `Name` property is what you're looking for: `Text="{Binding Name}"`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett,  `Text="{Binding Name}"` is exactly what I needed. Thanks for your help.